# yii phpunit getMockBuilder not working with --filter

Tags: php, yii, mocking, phpunit

In a Yii project, I am using phpunit with getMockbuilder.  When I run unit tests on the whole file, they all pass.  However, when I do `phpunit --filter testMyFunction`, I get the following error. "Call to undefined method Mock_Account_3a811374::__construct() ..."

After doing a little more checking I see that if the --filter ends up including a test that does not use the mock in addition to the one that does, then it works fine.

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix it?

Here's some of my code (simplified) ...

```
use components\Account;

class UtilsTest extends CDbTestCase
{
    ...
    public function testMyFunction()
    {
        $accountStub = $this->getMockBuilder('Account')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(array('methodToStub'))
            ->getMock();

        $accountStub->expects($this->any())
            ->method('methodToStub')
            ->will($this->returnValue(false));

        $accountStub->__construct();
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be that you get this because you disable the original constructor with the mock builder? This is why it works when you test the whole files... ?

Comment: @AresDraguna, I would think it should work even so.  I need to be able to disable the original constructor and call it later.

Comment: Uhm, `$this->betMockBuilder('Account')` I think it should be `$this->getMockBuilder('Account')` 

If you want to use __construct you should also mock it.

Comment: @Jhn, I'm not sure what you mean.  How can I use __construct and also mock it?  I either mock it or use it, right? My tests need to be able to call the real __construct function.  They work fine when the whole test class is called, but die when only one test function is called using --filter testMyFunction

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by what are are trying to do with `$accountStub->__construct()` when you have specified that you don't want to call the original constructor with `->disableOriginalConstructor()`?

You can call the constructor yourself and pass parameters with `setConstructorArgs(array $args)`. So this would look something like this:

```
$accountStub = $this->getMockBuilder('Account')
        ->setConstructorArgs($args)
        ->getMock();
```

However it wouldn't make sense to call this at the same time as `disableOriginalConstructor()`. I think you probably want to do one or the other.

I believe the error message you are getting is just PHP telling you that you are trying to do something that doesn't make sense. You are trying to call the constructor on an object that has already been constructed. What's more, you have even specifically told the mock to skip the call to the constructor method. PHP is just telling you that this method does not exist.

I think you probably just need to remove the following line and test again:

```
$accountStub->__construct();
```

Comment: If I remember right, the idea for using `disableOriginalConstructor` was to avoid having the constructor called on the `getMock()` call.  It needed to wait until after the `expects` stanza and then get called.  As I mentioned above, the tests work fine when the whole test class is called, but die when only one test function is called using --filter testMyFunction

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. Are you able to share any code from the other tests? It sounds like something is being done in one of the previous tests that's causing the test above to pass when run in sequence. Some kind of state that's not being cleared in the setup/teardown between tests. Without seeing the full code and what is happening in the other tests it's difficult to guess at what that state might be.